# ActionScript 3 button if currentframe

Tags: button, actionscript, if-statement, frame

I have a simple button and i want to make some transitions. 
If current frame is 1 I want to play frame 2.
If current frame is 2 I want to play frame 3.
If current frame is 3 I want to play frame 1.
Why my script doesn't work in ActionScript 3.0? Thanks.

```
buton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buton1Click);

function buton1Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
    if(currentFrame == 1){
      gotoAndStop(2); 
    }
    if(currentFrame == 2){
      gotoAndStop(3); 
    }
    if(currentFrame == 3){
      gotoAndStop(1); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `buton1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buton1Click);

function buton1Click(event:MouseEvent):void{
 if(currentFrame == 1){
   gotoAndPlay(2); 
 }
 else if(currentFrame == 2){
   gotoAndPlay(3); 
 }
 else if(currentFrame == 3){
   gotoAndPlay(1); 
 }
}
`

Comment: What happens when you click the button? Have you tried adding some `trace()` statements and running the debugger to see what your code is doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` blocks are always true - you move to the next frame and than test if you're on that frame.

Given your button spans timeline, like so:

[image: timeline]

Your code would be:

```
stop();

button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1Click);

function button1Click(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (currentFrame)
    {
        case 1:
            gotoAndStop(2);
            break;
        case 2:
            gotoAndStop(3);
            break;
        case 3:
            gotoAndStop(1);
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stop();
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, button1Click);

function button1Click(event:MouseEvent):void {
    this.gotoAndStop((this.currentFrame % this.totalFrames) + 1);
}

//this way you can change the timeline without changing code
```